# How to apply canActivate guard for all routes(master route and all sub routes) in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, canactivate, canactivatechild

I use Angular Guard to protect my routes, i add **canActivate** attr in master route and it works fine, while for sub single routes(ReportsRouteModule/RequestsRouteModule...), if i want to enable guard, i alse need to set canActivate in each routes, i think it's a bad way to use angular guard and waste a lot time. So is there any way to avoid it and manage it in the master route.

Please see my application structure and some code as below:
1. app structure:

```js
 |-- app.module.ts
 |-- app-routing.module.ts(master route)
 |-- app.component.ts
 |-- report
    |-- report-route.module.ts(sub route)
    |-- report-aa
    |-- report-bb
    |-- report-cc
 |-- request
    |-- request-route.module.ts(sub route)
    |-- request-aa
    |-- request-bb
    |-- request-cc
 |-- etc.
```

2. code:
   master route

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  // providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
```

sub route:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'reports',
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'reports', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'A', component: AReportsComponent},
      {path: 'B', component: BReportsComponent},
      {path: 'C', component: CReportsComponent},
    ]
  }

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [
    AReportsComponent,
    BReportsComponent,
    CReportsComponent,
   ]
})
export class ReportsRouteModule {

}
```

Comment: Please post your authguard also.

Answer (score 4):

You can place the routes inside a parent route and use the `canActive` on the parent route only. This way, the guard will match all child routes as well.

**Sample code**

```js
{
    path: "", 
    canActivate: [ParentAuthGaurdService], 
    children: [
        { path: "admin-dashboard", component: AdminDashboardComponent },
        { path: "admin/user", component: UserCrudComponent },
        { path: "admin/product", component: ProductCrudComponent }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some info on router internals, that will help you understand why adding `canACtivateGuards` to each of the sub-module's root route is not a bad practice.

When you use `Router`'s `forRoot` and `forChild`, it merges the sub-modules `routes` to parent module `routes` array. So these routes becomes **sibling routes**. This means, you have to add `canActivate` guard to each of the sub-module's top route.

If you do not want to do that, you have to mention all the other sub-routes as children to one parent route in app-routing as mentioned in the below answer(which is probably might not be what you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

As advised, i add `canActivate` in child routes and it works fine.